# Fgets - doesn't work in the loop

Tags: c, loops, fgets

The problem is that fgets doesn't take any value in the first iteration of the loop. Just simply skips it. As I see it. I get there is some basic mistake in my code, but I don't see it. Fgets starts taking values only on 2d iteration.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int t;
    scanf("%i", &t);

    char ways[100];
    for (int j = 0; j <= t; t++)
    {
        fgets (ways, 100, stdin);
        printf("Ways = %s\n", ways);
    }

    return 0; 
 }`
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your question. Note the #include's left out of your code.

Comment: Because the first `scanf` leaves a `newline` in the input buffer for `fgets` to read - don't mix your methods! Input to `t` with `fgets` and `sscanf`.

Comment: "gets doesn't take any value in the first iteration of the loop" --> Yes it did.  `fgets()` "took" the `'\n'` from the previous line.

Comment: Now I see. Thank you. so there are 2 issues.

Comment: Why are you increasing `t` instead of `j` in the for loop?, it seems an infinite loop

Comment: ...and of course `j <= t;` will give `t + 1` loops.

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is here:  If my input is 5 hello  scanf will read the 5 and assign it to t.  then the first iteration of the loop fgets will pull hello\n from the stdin, and printf will print "hello\n", any subsequent iteration will hang on fgets as the input is now empty.

Comment: @DaveS-- No, the subsequent calls to `fgets()` will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix your problem is to use `fgets()` and `sscanf()` to read the initial number. Also, it appears that your loop has a couple of errors. You probably meant `j < t` instead of `j <= t`, so that the loop executes `t` times. Also, you almost certainly meant to increment `j` instead of `t`, which would lead to an infinite loop.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int t;
    char buffer[100];
    fgets(buffer, 100, stdin);
    sscanf(buffer, "%i", &t);

    char ways[100];
    for (int j = 0; j < t; j++)
    {
        fgets (ways, 100, stdin);
        printf("Ways = %s\n", ways);
    }

    return 0; 
 }
```

Note that it is generally a bad idea to add a white-space character to the end of a format string, as this causes `scanf()` to continue trying to read input until a non-white-space character is encountered, blocking the input.

Answer (score -2):

scanf() is reading the digits the uder entered, and leaving his trailing spaces and newline in the buffer. fgets() then reads these and so appears to read an empty string on the first iteration.

To fix add a whitespace character after the %i. Whitespace matches whitespace with scanf.

Comment: A white-space at the end of the format string will continue matching white-space characters until a non-white-space character is encountered, causing the input to hang.